# Does the mysql commands "GRANT ALL ON database_name.* to 'database_username'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'database_password'; a security risk

Tags: mysql

I am having a concern that Are these commands give full access to anyone to get in mysql easily, even if there is a password?

```
  GRANT ALL ON database_name.* to 'database_username'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'database_password';

  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

  SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "database_username";
```

Comment: Well it looks like the person would need to be a the specified IP address and know the user name and (I Hope) Very Strong Password. Oh and you only give access to one database, which is good

Comment: It would be better to NOT `GRANT ALL` and instead be specific which privilages you are giving this user

Comment: Are you concerned because you think `GRANT ALL` means any client can connect without a password? That's not the case. `ALL` does not refer to authentication, it refers to things the client can do after they have authenticated.

Comment: Bill Karwin, Yes, I do have a concern. So it means that it is not a big security concern.